# CSS Background image not showing up in Github Pages

Tags: css, github-pages

My background image is not showing up when I open my GitHub pages. I've tried using both the actual pathway and Relative pathway but results are the same. This exact code works fine in VS Code in the live server so I do not know what the problem is, as I'm not getting any type of error message from GitHub. The picture is of the CSS file. Is this a code or GitHub problem??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aKNU.png)

Comment: Could you please post the code here directly as text instead of an image?

Answer (score 0):

Your root directory has **index, img folder and css folder**. Since you are in css folder you have to add `..` to your path to go one level up `../img/background.jpg`, this will do the work